# Internal microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.10 on a Lenovo yoga slim 7 14are05

Tags: lenovo, microphone, 20.10

Recently made dual boot on my Lenovo yoga slim 7 (amd). The microphone has been working from the start. All of a sudden it stopped being detected in settings/sound. I have now made a fresh install of Ubuntu, and it still isn't detected in settings. In windows the microphone works.

I've been using Ubuntu for a couple of years but i'm definitely not very skilled at this.

Solutions i have tried:
In Pulseaudio there is no input device detected.
I have tried to make some alterations to the /etc/pulse/default.pa, without luck.

In alsamixer there are two sound cards, one of them has capture controls.
How do I get that second card being used? Maybe that's not the way forward, I could really need some help here.

Appreciate all the help I can get!

EDIT: By chance I found that the issue is with kernel 5.8.0-44.50. Using an older kernel has solved my microphone problem.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled over the solution to this. The issue is with kernel 5.8.0-44.50. Using an older kernel has solved my microphone problem.

Comment: What kernel do you use instead? I tried 5.7.19. It doesn't help...